# I want to change Userpoints block format

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

On my home page i can view a userpoint block with below format.

```
My userpoints balance
    General: 1 Total (all categories): 1
    View userpoints transactions
    Add or deduct userpoints
```

However i have more categories for Userpoints apart from General . e.g. CommunityLove , Intelligence e.t.c.
How can i add them

I want it like this.

```
My userpoints balance
    General: 1
    CommunityLove: 0
    Intelligence: 0 Total (all categories): 1
    View userpoints transactions
    Add or deduct userpoints
```

How would i achieve this?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks parthi for quick response. I tried looking out for views but didn't get it :(. Where do i need to check this block?

Comment: it seems there is view integration for this module. so it will be possible to get the desired result. or else try block alter.

Comment: Block alter you mean configure?
I click on block (using admin ) it gives me an option to configure the block . but it gives me only 4 settings for block. 
pages,
content type,
roles,
users 
I m not able to edit content. Also i checked views--> list this block is nowhere present. IF you install userpoint module you get this block by default.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7

Comment: looks bit geeky to me .. Any simple solution will be appreciated (If applicable :( ) Any video link on how to use hooks ..